# Any advice on index row referencing when trying to drag the formula down?

Tags: excel

I am trying to reference data that is inserted into excel from Microsoft forms. I originally tried to use just regular cell referencing, but realized that the cell references changed each time a form answer was submitted (because each form answer would automatically insert a new row). So I am now trying to use and index function to pull the data from the Microsoft form excel sheet. This is the code I have so far:

```
=INDEX('[Quarterly Starts Test 1 1.xlsx]Form1'!A:A,1)
```

When I drag this formula horizontally it changes the column reference as expected (ie. from A to B and then to C) but when I drag the formula down it won't change the row reference. Is there an easy way to have the formula add 1 to the row reference for each row I drag the formula into? (i.e from 1 to 2 to 3....)

Comment: Reference a sheet that will not have its rows deleted: `=INDEX('[Quarterly Starts Test 1 1.xlsx]Form1'!A:A,ROW(Sheet2!A1))`  given that sheet2 is hidden or guaranteed not to have its rows deleted.

Comment: Isn't the formula ROW what you need?

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner! The formula works perfectly. You saved me from a massive amount of data entry and for that I am grateful!